# javascript click one text and it will filter a hidden list to pop up

Tags: javascript

I would like to click on one word, then it will act as a filter to show the hidden list. 
my code is, but it does not work, can someone please tell me what is wrong with my scripts. 
in fact this is what I am looking for: In the webpage, there are some hidden lists, there are open list, when I click on one item on the open list, it will act as a filter to filter the hidden list and pop up the filtered list. :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<div id="myInput" onclick="myFunction()">

 <li>Adele</li>
 <li>Agnes</li>
 <li>Billy</li>
 <li>Bob</li>


</div>
<div style="display:none" id="myDIV">
<ul id="myUL">
  
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

</ul>
</div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    var input1, input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input1 = document.getElementById("myInput");
    input = input1.getElementByTagName("li");
    filter = input.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
   
    
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please hit F12 and fix the errors in the console - getElementsByTagname is plural

Comment: Use querySelector: `input = input1.querySelector("li");`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use querySelectorAll to shortcut
2. Add click handlers to the first LIs instead of to the div
3. Save the clicked name to toggle the display
4. Wrap the LIs in a UL to create valid HTML

```js
var saveFilter = "";
window.onload = function() {
  var triggers = document.querySelectorAll("#myInput>ul>li");
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    triggers[i].onclick = function() {
      var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDIV'),
        filter = this.innerText.toUpperCase();
      if (saveFilter === filter) {
        myDiv.style.display = myDiv.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
      } else {
        myDiv.style.display = "block"; // new name
      }
      saveFilter = filter;

      var li = document.querySelectorAll("#myUL>li");
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        var a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        li[i].style.display = a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ? "" : "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<div id="myInput">
  <ul>
    <li>Adele</li>
    <li>Agnes</li>
    <li>Billy</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
  </ul>

</div>
<div style="display:none" id="myDIV">
  <ul id="myUL">

    <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, it works. If I wan to show the filtered contents in a pop up?